# MongoDB: Adding member to replica set triggers election in 3.2.11?

Tags: mongodb-replica-set

What are the scenarios that cause mongodb to trigger an election on `rs.add()`?

In version 3.2.11, I have seen multiple times that adding/removing member to replica set does not trigger an election.

Contrary, in version 2.6,  most of the times on `rs.add()/rs.remove()` calls would trigger election.

From [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/rs.add/#behavior), `rs.add()` can, in some cases, trigger an election.

What are the possible situations that may trigger an election?  How can I completely avoid the election during `rs.add()`?

PS: There are some scenarios where we don't want an election to be triggered.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the logs, to see if they say anything about why the election is being called?

Comment: Election wasn't triggered any time

Answer (score 0):

Election is triggered at least in scenario when you include "priority" information with node name.

Comment: The above add method includes priority. But does not trigger an election